# Express $z = \dfrac{3i}{\sqrt{2-i}} +1$ in the form $a + bi$, where $a, b \in\Bbb R$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Express $$z = \frac{3i}{\sqrt{2-i}} +1$$ in the form $a + bi$, where $a, b \in\Bbb R$.

I figure for this one I multiply by the conjugate of $\sqrt{2 +1}$? But I’m still struggle to achieve the form $a+bi$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If I am correct, you want to express $z=\frac {3i}{\sqrt {2-i}}+1$ in the form of $a+bi$.

Comment: Is it this:  $$z=\frac{3i}{\sqrt 2 -i} +1$$  ????

Comment: Yep sorry trying my best I do apologize!

Comment: Wait wasn't is $\sqrt {2-i}$?

Comment: @MissPolite which form?  Mine or Mohammad's?

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate yep the whole denominator is square rooted 2-i

Comment: @MissPolite The answer will involve the polar form.  Have you studied polar form conversion for complex numbers yet???

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate is that the rCIS(theta) and r(cos(theta) and isin(theta)) ?? We've touched on it

Comment: @MissPolite yes...  $r  \cis \theta = r (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) = r e^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna need to convert $\sqrt {2-i}$ to the form $\alpha + i \beta$.

To do that, convert to polar

$$ 2-i=r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$$

So that

$$\sqrt{2-i}=\sqrt r \cdot (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^{1/2} = \sqrt r \cdot \left(\cos \frac{\theta}{2}+i \sin \frac{\theta}{2}\right) $$

Some of the ingredients are:

$$r=\sqrt{2^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt 5, \quad \cos \theta= \frac{2}{\sqrt 5}, \quad \sin \theta =\frac{-1}{\sqrt 5} $$

$\theta$ will be a negative angle, so that

$$\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}} \qquad \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \theta}{2}}$$

Continuing

$$\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}{2}}= \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 5+2}{2\sqrt 5}}=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 5}}{\sqrt 2 \sqrt r}$$

$$\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}=-\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}{2}}= -\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 5-2}{2\sqrt 5}}=-\frac{\sqrt{-2+\sqrt 5}}{\sqrt 2 \sqrt r}$$

Making

$$\sqrt{2-i}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 5}}{\sqrt 2}\right)-i \left(\frac{\sqrt{-2+\sqrt 5}}{\sqrt 2 }\right) \in \alpha + i \beta$$

Comment: $2-i$ is under the square root, not just the $2$.

Comment: I am unsure but the title is showing $z=\frac{3i}{\sqrt{2-i}} +1$.

Comment: @Clayton I've now completely changed my answer

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan It's been edited

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate Yep that's what was asked, thank you I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle z=\frac{3i}{\sqrt{2}-i+1}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{3i}{\sqrt{2}-i+1}\times\frac{\sqrt{2}+i+1}{\sqrt{2}+i+1}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{-3+(3+\sqrt{2})i}{(\sqrt{2}+1)^2+1}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{-3+(3+\sqrt{2})i}{4+2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Check the question.

Comment: Sorry Daruma I didn't write it very well thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\dfrac{3i}{\sqrt{2-i}}+1=\dfrac{3i+\sqrt{2-i}}{\sqrt{2-i}}$$
Now $$=\dfrac{3i+\sqrt{2-i}}{\sqrt{2-i}}\times \dfrac{\sqrt{2+i}}{\sqrt{2+i}}$$$$=\dfrac{3i\sqrt{2+i}+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$=\dfrac{3i\sqrt{2+i}}{\sqrt{5}}+\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: I assume that the $\frac {3i\sqrt {10+5i}}{5}$ cannot be further simplified to the form $bi$?

Comment: Any complex number can be written in the form $a+bi$ (just recall that for any $z\in\Bbb C$, we can write $z=re^{i\theta}$).

Comment: @Clayton thank you for reminding me of that.

Comment: @Clayton where did the initial first line of text get the root 2-i on top?

Comment: @MissPolite: We have $1=\frac{\sqrt{2-i}}{\sqrt{2-i}}$. Now there is a common denominator, so you can add the two fractions and keep the same denominator.

Comment: @Clayton Yep, but where did the denomiator of the 1 go?  It's like it was combined but doesn't become 2 root 2- i. Gosh I've really got to learn this coding.

Comment: @MissPolite: Recall that we have $\frac ab+\frac cb=\frac{a+c}{b}$. For a concrete example, think of $\frac12+\frac12=\frac{1+1}{2}=\frac22=1$.

Comment: @Clayton yep I've offically... gone crazy. 3.51am and struggling with my assignment tomorrow. Due in 6 hours sorry to be a bother.

Comment: Complex numbers do not (in general) satisfy $\sqrt z \sqrt w= \sqrt{zw}$. So, your logic doesn’t work and the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is a question, to me, anyway, whether the expression is $\frac{3i}{\sqrt{2}- i}+ 1$ which is what daruma answered, or $\frac{3i}{\sqrt{2- i}}+ 1$.  If it is the latter then $2- i= \sqrt{5}e^{-2i\pi/3}$ so that $\sqrt{2- i}= \sqrt[4]{5}e^{-i\pi/3}$.  In "Cartesian form" that is $\sqrt[4]{5}(cos(\pi/3)- i sin(\pi/3))$. Its conjugate is $\sqrt[4]{5}(cos(\pi/3)+ i sin(\pi/3))$

Comment: Are you sure about that angle??  I don't think it's $\frac {\pi}{3} $ exactly